# Cucumber features failing "undefined method `Factory'" with bundler, rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot, bundler

rake cucumber --trace

output:

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I "/home/vadim/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.3/lib:lib" "/home/vadim/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.3/bin/cucumber"  --profile default
Using the default profile...
...
Given I signed up with "username/email@person.com/password" # features/step_definitions/clearance_steps.rb:13
      undefined method `Factory' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x..fdb6a5bc0> (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/clearance_steps.rb:14:in `/^I signed up with "(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)"$/'
      features/sign_in.feature:14:in `Given I signed up with "username/email@person.com/password"
...
13 scenarios (13 failed)
83 steps (13 failed, 70 skipped)
0m0.769s
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I "/home/vadim/.bundle/r...]
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:995
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `sh'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `sh'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1029:in `ruby'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `ruby'
/home/vadim/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.3/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:68:in `run'
/home/vadim/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.8.3/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:138
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

System: Rails 2.3.5 running on Ubuntu 9.04

bundler (0.9.26)
RubyGems 1.3.7
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]

Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
gem "rails", "2.3.5"
gem "mysql"
gem "clearance"
gem "formtastic"
gem "haml"
gem "geokit"

group :development do
  gem "mongrel"
end

group :test do
  gem "factory_girl"
  gem 'rspec', '>=1.3.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>=1.3.2'
end

group :cucumber do
  gem "factory_girl"
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '>=0.3.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '>=0.5.0'
  gem 'webrat', '>=0.7.0'
  gem 'rspec', '>=1.3.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>=1.3.2'
end
```

Bundle Install Output

```
Using rake (0.8.7) from bundler gems 
Using activesupport (2.3.5) from bundler gems 
Using rack (1.0.1) from bundler gems 
Using actionpack (2.3.5) from bundler gems 
Using actionmailer (2.3.5) from bundler gems 
Using activerecord (2.3.5) from bundler gems 
Using activeresource (2.3.5) from bundler gems 
Using builder (2.1.2) from bundler gems 
Using cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0) from bundler gems 
Using clearance (0.8.8) from bundler gems 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2) from bundler gems 
Using trollop (1.16.2) from bundler gems 
Using gherkin (2.0.2) from bundler gems 
Using json_pure (1.4.3) from bundler gems 
Using term-ansicolor (1.0.5) from bundler gems 
Using cucumber (0.8.3) from bundler gems 
Using cucumber-rails (0.3.2) from bundler gems 
Using daemons (1.1.0) from bundler gems 
Using database_cleaner (0.5.2) from bundler gems 
Using factory_girl (1.3.1) from bundler gems 
Using fastthread (1.0.7) from bundler gems 
Using formtastic (0.9.10) from bundler gems 
Using gem_plugin (0.2.3) from bundler gems 
Using geokit (1.5.0) from bundler gems 
Using haml (3.0.13) from bundler gems 
Using mongrel (1.1.5) from bundler gems 
Using mysql (2.8.1) from bundler gems 
Using nokogiri (1.4.2) from bundler gems 
Using rack-test (0.5.4) from bundler gems 
Using rails (2.3.5) from bundler gems 
Using rspec (1.3.0) from bundler gems 
Using rspec-rails (1.3.2) from bundler gems 
Using webrat (0.7.1) from bundler gems 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Poor cucumber looks like it's in trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with bundler crapping out because I declared factory_girl in more than one group.  http://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/issue/135  Until this fix is incorporated into a release, either pull down the bundler gem from github or don't put a gem in your Gemfile into more than one group.